# Time reversal symmetry and real symmetric Hamiltonian matrix

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, time-reversal-symmetry

In the literature (like those in quantum chaos), it seems that time-reversal symmetry implies that the Hamiltonian of the system is a real symmetric one, instead of just being complex Hermitian.

Is there any rigorous justification about this link?

Answer (score 5):

A time reversal operator is an [anti-unitary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-symmetry#Anti-unitary_representation_of_time_reversal), which can be expressed as:

$\mathcal{T}=UK$

where $K$ denotes complex conjugate and $U$ is a unitary operator. In case of spinless particles, $U$ is chosen to be Identity. Thus $\mathcal{T}=K$.

If the system has $\mathcal{T}$-reversal symmetry:

$$
KH\psi=HK\psi
$$

which leads to:

$$
H^*\psi^*=H\psi^*
$$
meaning that the Hamiltonian must be real symmetric.