# $(H\Psi(x,t))^*=H\Psi^*(x,t)$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space

In the solutions of an exercise I got confused about the following equality

$$(H\Psi(x,t))^*=H\Psi^*(x,t).$$

Is this true in general? Or in special cases?

It seems to imply that H is a real matrix which is obviously not the case in general.

Also it was used that

$$\langle x|H| x'\rangle=\langle x'|H| x\rangle$$

which also cannot be for a general Hamiltonian.

Answer (score 3):

Physical observables, such as the hamiltonian are expressed via Hermitian operators, and as such always produce real eigenvalues, and as such your first expression is true in general.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Well yes, if $\Psi$ is an eigenstate it obviously follows that $(H\Psi)^*=(E\Psi)^*=E\Psi^*$ but is this equal to $H\Psi^*$ in gneral? Because writing it out we have $(H\Psi)^*=H^*\Psi^*$ as it is only complex conjugation, no?

Answer (score 2):

This property of a hamiltonian is known as [**hermiticity**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-adjoint_operator), and it is obeyed by all physical observables in quantum mechanics.

In wavefunction language this is easy to prove. If $H$ is a combination of derivatives and real-valued functions, like for example
$$
\hat H=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+V(x),
$$
then the complex conjugate of $\hat H\Psi(x,t)=-\tfrac{\hbar^2}{2m}\tfrac{\partial^2\Psi}{\partial x^2}(x,t)+V(x)\Psi(x,t)$ is simply $\hat H$ applied to $\Psi(x,t)^\ast$.

In inner product notation, the hermiticity of $\hat H$ means that the inner product between $\hat H\psi$ and some other state $\phi$ can be expressed as
$$
\left\langle\phi,\hat H\psi\right\rangle=\left\langle\hat H\phi,\psi\right\rangle.
$$
This includes in particular the fact that
$$\langle x|\hat H| x'\rangle=\langle x'|\hat H| x\rangle ^*$$
as long as $\hat H$ is hermitian (note the complex conjugation).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The equation above says something stronger than H being hermitian, it says that H is real. Actually I found more or less what I was looking for: for a time symmtric system it seems to be known that the Hamiltonian is real. It would be nice to see a proof. The only one I found is the following: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/191275/time-reversal-symmetry-and-real-symmetric-hamiltonian-matrix